# Transistors at high frequency

Tags: transistors, power-electronics, high-frequency

I'm a newbie,
I need to know the relation between high frequency and circuit size, as I read before that I high frequency transistor size need to be small to deliver the full wave length and I need explanation !!

Comment: Not sure what you read, and what frequency you are talking about. But, not necessarily so. As long as you can match into the device is what counts.

Comment: Impedance matching (for given frequency range) is actually more important.

Answer (score 2):

More details on where you read this would provide context to narrow down answers but here are some general points that may help.

"smaller" could mean in terms of physical size or in terms of power capability.

Physical size - as frequency increases, parasitics (such as series inductance) need to be smaller. Transistors in physically larger packages tend to have higher parasitics which can degrade the ability to match impedances. Difficulty can mean hard to match broadband or ending up being very sensitive to slight changes in transistor characteristics (e.g. over temperature) or component values.. At very high frequencies the package interconnect can electrically be considered a transmission line or Integral matching component.

In terms of power, as frequency increases, the maximum practical power that a single transistor can provide is smaller. Primarily it's because a power transistor consists of many small transistors connected together in parallel. The input signal splits into each mini transistor, is amplified, then is combined back together. This needs to happen such that the signals combine in phase. As frequency increases, the feed networks in and out of the mini transistors becomes more complex and more lossy, rendering the transistor less efficient.

In terms of overall circuit size, it's hard to generalize too much. However, components like capacitors, inductors and transmission lines tend to scale in value and in size inversely with frequency. So, an "equivalent" amplifier at 10GHz will be smaller than at 1GHz or 100MHz.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what type of performance you want - do you want high bandwidth from a base band perspective, or do you want to talk about RF performance, where we have narrow-band signals around a carrier?

In the case of a baseband system, you want lower parasitics (capacitance tends to dominate in every single IC base band application, together with trace resistance). Smaller transistors can give you that lower parasitic capacitance, which is why the performance of circuits increased with every new CMOS node, and now your 'standard' 28nm and below can do 50 Gbit/s if you really know what you are doing.

When it comes to making RF circuits, you don't necessarily care about the size of the parasitics (though they do matter, due to something called the bode-fano limit). What you do care about is the loss, usually expressed as quality factor, of these parasitics, and how well they are accessible.

At a given frequency, you can tune out capacitors with inductors. This only works at a single frequency, though, so is not suited to broad-band and base-band systems (there are inductor-peaking systems used but that is for another day). What is actually very interesting about inductors is that on-chip, they become better with higher frequencies. At 2.4 GHz, an on-chip inductor is huge, and has a lot of loss. Capacitors (asin, desired capacitors built by purposefully putting metal next to other metal on chip) perform well.

This flips at higher frequencies (higher frequencies here being 10's of GHz - so well into millimeter-wave frequencies). The inductors get smaller, and the fields start sticking closer to the metals, so you have less substrate losses as a result. This makes inductor-based tuning very attractive at 50-200 GHz frequencies, which is why this is something you see in research.

Just compare the size of inductors on this 2.4 GHz ISM chip \$[1]\$:
[image]

With this 390 GHz transmitter \$[2]\$:
[image]

Keep in mind that these two chips are about the same size (2mm by 1 mm), but on the first, all you see is inductors, but on the second, you need to actually put effort in to see the inductors. (I count 14 inductors/transformer pairs just inside a single 'PA+Multiplier' block in the second image)

So what is the limit? Well, lets look back at something I said a bit earlier: "What you do care about is the loss, usually expressed as quality factor, of these parasitics, and how well **they are accessible**. "

What do I mean with "accessible"? Well, the gate contact of a transistor is a capacitor. This is the capacitor we want to often tune out with our inductors. But this inductor can't be directly connected to that capacitor - our gate also has some resistance. This resistance limits our ability to compensate for the capacitor. This is one reason why we can't just make circuits work at any frequency we want. As the transistors have gotten smaller, we lower the capacitor and generally can reduce the gate resistance too since that contact length can decrease, and so achieve better performance.

And I realize now after typing all this that you might have been looking more at discrete power-devices and not on-chip devices, but I'm gonna leave this here anyways in case someone is interested.

\$[1]\$ H. Jhon, I. Song, I. M. Kang and H. Shin, "2.4 GHz ISM-Band Receiver Design in a 0.18 \$\mu{\hbox{m}}\$ Mixed Signal CMOS Process," in IEEE Microwave and Wireless Components Letters, vol. 17, no. 10, pp. 736-738, Oct. 2007, doi: 10.1109/LMWC.2007.905641.

\$[2]\$ A. Standaert and P. Reynaert, "A Packaged Fully Digital 390GHz Harmonic Outphasing Transmitter in 28nm CMOS," 2019 IEEE Asian Solid-State Circuits Conference (A-SSCC), Macau, Macao, 2019, pp. 149-152, doi: 10.1109/A-SSCC47793.2019.9056947.

Answer (score -3):

In the 1920s and 1930s, people developed measurement methods that could measure amplitude as well as phase. The company General Radio was a key provider of equipment, often using reactive bidges (AC bridges).

Comment: This feels like a non sequitur. Did you mean to post this on a different queestion?

Comment: Please edit this question or delete it